# mysqli_result and mysqli_stmt extending

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have successfully extended the MySQLi class in PHP, however I am having issues correctly extending and then implementing the mysqli_result and mysqli_stmt classes after being extended. I have looked through https://github.com/php/php-src which is supposed to contain all the PHP source code and I have been unable to locate these classes to extrapolate a solution. If anyone could provide an example with the mysqli_result class being extended and implemented, and then another with the mysqli_stmt class being extended and implemented that would be greatly appreciated. Either that or the source files to the mysqli_result and mysqli_stmt classes so I can determine a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to say _extended_ rather than _overloaded_? The two refer to different concepts.

Comment: ...and PHP doesn't directly support function overloading...

Comment: Incidentally, the source for the MySQLi class resides in the [`ext/` directory here](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/mysqli) but this is the source code in C which compiles to the extension binary, not a PHP class source file.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I did indeed mean to say extended, I'll make the edit to correct the wording.